# Advice on AIX system to compile on or shell I can rent

Tags: aix

I am a single developer and I have a small app that I sell. All of my customers have been on Solaris. I purchased an old E450 off ebay and compile and test happily.

Now I have been asked a few times about an AIX build. I know nothing about AIX. So could someone please help me with the following, thanks:

Is there a shell I can rent with cc or gcc that anyone knows about?
I have been told the version I have to support is 5L 5.3 I have searched ebay and couldn't find a server without spending thousands. Can anyone suggest something for a few hundred pounds?
I assume, like solaris and sparc, the power5 machines have their own cpu type thus I can't install any virtual OS on another hardware etc?

Comment: This seems like a good question to have answered, though it may need some tweaking to bring it up to something useful. I've started a meta discussion to see what the best way to answer this would be: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362776/where-is-the-best-place-to-answer-how-do-i-get-a-virtual-host-for-developing-on

Comment: Resource recommendation questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: StackOverflow will not provide recommendations for any off-site services because of the slippery spammy slope this can start: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251134/where-can-i-ask-about-finding-a-tool-library-or-favorite-off-site-resource

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try it

http://www.polarhome.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can rent a whole LPAR (virtual machine) in the Cloud and choose AIX version you need. 
Try this site: http://www.lparbox.com